Tradingview widget - how to call save_image function?
I'm trying to find a way to save the chart that the tradingview widget generates from the code.
When i open https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js, i see that a save_image function is defined along with other functions, is there a way to call that function in javascript? Do i have to find another way to save an image of the chart?
Here is what i tried:
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="height:100%;width:100%">
    <div id="tradingview_009af"></div>
    <div id="basic-area-chart-demo" style="height:calc(100% - 32px);width:100%"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span></a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget(
        {
          "autosize": true,
          "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
          "interval": "D",
          "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
          "theme": "dark",
          "style": "1",
          "locale": "en",
          "enable_publishing": false,
          "allow_symbol_change": true,
            "save_image": true,
          "studies": [
            "STD;RSI"
          ],
          "container_id": "tradingview_009af"
        }
    );

    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        try {
          var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          if (data.provider === 'TradingView' && data.name === 'widgetReady') {
            console.log("The TradingView chart widget is fully loaded and ready!");
            widget.save_image();
          }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
</script>

I tried to call widget.save_image() but it will raise a TypeError: widget.save_image is not a function error. Is there any way to save this? The widget has a button that let's you save an image of the chart locally, so i thought that it would be possible to call that function from my code too. Thanks in advance!

That's because there isn't a save_image method on the widget object. You should have a look at the documentation of that JavaScript file I'm afraid.

@DouwedeHaan thanks for your answer. The problem is that i didn't manage to find a documentation for that

What about the “takeClientScreenshot” approach mentioned in https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/ui_elements/Snapshots/
